# Mule attachment returning values

Tags: mule

```
<flow..>
    ...
    <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.rest.SyncAccountService"/>
    </jersey:resources>
    <set-payload value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    <set-property propertyName="mimeType" value="application/octet-stream" doc:name="Property"/>
    <set-property propertyName="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=${file_name}" doc:name="Property"/> 
    <set-variable variableName="status" value="Success" doc:name="Status"/>
    <flow-ref name="audit" doc:name="audit"/>
</flow>

<flow name="audit" doc:name="audit">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${hostname}" port="${glport}" path="audit" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <db:insert config-ref="QB_Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Audit" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO SIAS_AUDIT(ACCESS_ID,EMPLID) VALUES('1','value1')]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <set-payload value="===Audit Log ===" name="AuditStatus" doc:name="Status"/>
</flow>
```

Above code works fine, but it returns ===Audit Log === in the downloaded file. Instead of this I need to display the payload defined at the attachment level which is generated at rest component.

Purpose of Audit flow is to record the status of success/failure in the db which should not return anything. If I remove `<set-payload value="===Audit Log ==="  name="AuditStatus" doc:name="Status"/>`

it starts returning java.lang.Number

**EDIT**

Getting following error, after making it as async:

```
ERROR 2015-05-27 13:43:51,846 [[qbiif].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously. Message payload is of type: MuleResponseWriter$1
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:

    1. Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously. Message payload is of type: MuleResponseWriter$1 (org.mule.api.MessagingException)
      org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor:132 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/MessagingException.html)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Root Exception stack trace:
    org.mule.api.MessagingException: Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously. Message payload is of type: MuleResponseWriter$1
```

Flow changes:

```
<flow name="audit" doc:name="audit" processingStrategy="asynchronous">   
    <db:insert config-ref="QB_Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Audit" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO SIAS_AUDIT(ACCESS_ID,EMPLID) VALUES('1','value1')]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:insert>
    <set-payload value="===Audit Log ===" name="AuditStatus" doc:name="Status"/>
</flow>
```

**EDIT-2**

Final changes for working code after following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998604/mule-processing-strategies-call-async-private-flow-from-synchronous-flow)

```
<flow name="audit" doc:name="audit">   
    <async>
        <db:insert config-ref="QB_Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Audit" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO SIAS_AUDIT(ACCESS_ID,EMPLID) VALUES('1','value1')]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:insert>
        <set-payload value="===Audit Log ===" name="AuditStatus" doc:name="Status"/>
    </async>
</flow>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the `http:inbound-endpoint` in the `audit` flow? Do you intend to call this flow directly over HTTP?

Comment: @DavidDossot, removed it. Not required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove `<set-payload value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>` : it sets the message payload as itself, which is useless.
- Wrap `<flow-ref name="audit" doc:name="audit"/>` in an `async` scope so its response doesn't mess with the response from the JAX-RS component.
- Unless you really need to expose the `audit` flow over HTTP, remove the `http:inbound-endpoint` in it.

Comment: Removed http inbound endpoint and payload. After making changes for Async error as, getting Unable to process a synchronous event asynchronously. Updated question above

Comment: got it, wrapped with <async>